# Arduino passing multidimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, function, arduino

I am writing a small program that plays a song on a buzzer.
I am creating a function that expects a two dimensional array.
The array can contain unlimited rows and two coloumns.
The first column contains a previously defined constant, which is the frequency of the note and the second is the length.

I googled how to pass an array to a function and I think I am doing as I read but for some reason the function does nothing.
As I figured out adding some Serial.print() calls, I found out that the function sees a 0 length array.

```
//Definitons of frequencies and pinout and tempo

...

unsigned int mySong[][2]{

                      {G2, 2}, 
                      {B2, 1}, 
                      {D3, 1}, 
                      {G3, 2}

                    };

void playSong(unsigned int song[][2])
{
  Serial.println(sizeof(song)/sizeof(song[0]));

  for(int i = 0; i<sizeof(song)/sizeof(song[0]); i++)
  {
     tone(buzzerPin, song[i][0], (song[i][1]*tempo));
     Serial.println(song[i][0]);Serial.println(song[i][1]);
     delay(song[i][1]*tempo);
   }
}

void setup() {
  pinMode(buzzerPin, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  playSong(mySong);
}
```

But if I change every 'song' to 'mySong', it works fine and plays the music and the readings in the serial monitor are correct, so it suggests that the way I found out should be good, and the array and constants should also work fine, so the data gets lost when I am passing it to the function.

What may I be doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When passing arrays as arguments to functions the arrays *decays to pointers* to their first element. So even when you write

```
void playSong(unsigned int song[][2])
```

the compiler will treat it as

```
void playSong(unsigned int (*song)[2])
```

That means that doing `sizeof(song)` will not work, as you then will get the size of the *pointer* and not the data it points to. You need to pass the first "dimension" as an argument as well:

```
void playSong(unsigned int song[][2], size_t num_elements)
```

Then when you *call* the `playSong` function you can use the `sizeof` "trick" to get the number of elements (if *and only if* it is an actual array and not a pointer):

```
playSong(mySong, sizeof mySong / sizeof mySong[0]);
```

Comment: you can also define the array length function
`#define arrayLength( x ) (sizeof (x) / sizeof (x[0]))`
and then use it as:
`playSong(mySong, arrayLength(mySong));`

Answer (score 1):

Twodimensional arrays are only the scond best choice in most cases.
I prefer to have a one-dimensional array of dedicated items.

```
struct Tone {unsigned int freq; byte duration;};
Tone mySong[] {
           {G2, 2}, 
           {B2, 1}, 
           {D3, 1}, 
           {G3, 2}
 };
```

Of course Joachim's reply about the unknown size, when supplying a Tone song[] parameter, is true as well.
Either supply number of elements as an extra parameter, or define a

const Tone EndOfSong {0,0};